# Change category type of multiple columns using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset from kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/chirin/africa-economic-banking-and-systemic-crisis-data) and I am trying to change the data types of these columns from integer to category all at once using the following code:

```
  cols = (df['systemic_crisis'], df['independence'], df['currency_crises'], df['inflation_crises'])
    for col in cols:
        col = col.astype('category')

    df.info()
```

But apparently it doesn't work and the data types are still int64 instead of category. What did I do wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nor changing datatype of actual dataframe but changing the datatypes the tuple that you created using

`(df['systemic_crisis'], df['independence'], df['currency_crises'], df['inflation_crises'])`

You need:

```
cols = ['systemic_crisis','independence','currency_crises','inflation_crises']
for col in cols:
   df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
```

**Edit**

As @Jon Clements said you can also use

```
df.update(df[cols].astype('category'))
```

Comment: can you clarify the complete code? I used your code and it changed ALL columns in the table to category instead of the ones I want.

Comment: You could possibly also do: `df.update(df[cols].astype('category'))`...